# ¿Como establecer un setOnClickListener en un Fragment en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo un listado en un navegation drawer, llame los datos correctamente pero ahora que en cada dato del listado le puse un boton para que haga un accion el valor de este me vota null, a pesar de que se relacionan, no entiendo porque.
He intentado de diferentes manera pero me vota el mismo error, intente estableciendo como Implement el ListenerOnclick y nada.

ERROR: aparece apesar de que estan enlazados los datos

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.martapp, PID: 22476
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.martapp.HomeFragment.onViewCreated(HomeFragment.java:70)
```

MI LAYOUT PARA EL LIST: esta dentro de un cardview, luego en otro layout esta llamado en recyclerview.

```
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/imgpedido"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="30dp"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginStart="84dp"
          android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
          android:src="@drawable/imgpedido"
          android:textStyle="bold" />
```

MI FRAGMENT: aqui aparece el problema cuando llamo para dar clic en un imageview

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment{

public String TAG="SISTEMA";
LinearLayout listcli;
SQLiteDatabase db;
dbMartellApp xdba ;
private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

ImageView btnped,btncobra,btnvisit;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    final View v = view;
    final Bundle sis= savedInstanceState;

    /*************************************/
    btnped=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgpedido);
    btncobra=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgcobrar);
    btnvisit=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imgvisit);

    btnped.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e(TAG, "pedidooooooo");
        }
    });
}
```

VISTA PRINCIPAL DEL NAVEGATION LLAMANDO AL FRAGMENT: esta clase es la principal donde cambia entre los fragment pero la estableci para que se vea primero.

```
public class caNavigation extends AppCompatActivity implements  NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{
public String TAG="SISTEMA";
List<EntiListCliente> elements;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
SQLiteDatabase db;
dbMartellApp xdba ;
public TextView xtitulo;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_canavigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Fragment fragment=new HomeFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main,fragment).commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Para solucionar este problema debes asegurar que en el layout  `fragment_home.xml` que carga tu `HomeFragment` ,

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
 }
```

se tenga el botón con id `imgpedido`